# Selecting highest value within group using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, select

I have a .shp of points. This points are organized in groups with same ID (group 1, 2 ,3)

Each group has 10 points.

Each point has a Z column with Z values.

I want to select the point with the highest Z value for each group.

So just one point should be selected for each group.

I was trying "select by expression" but I don't know what expression to use.

Also, I need a way to automatize this. This process is just a small part of my project that needs to be repeated a bunch of times, so doing this manually all the time is impossible. A way to use do this with graphical modeler would be great.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Select by Expression using this expression to select the point with the highest Z value for each ID group:

```
"z" = maximum("z","ID")
```

---

> **function maximum** 
>   Returns the aggregate maximum value from a field or expression.
>
> **Syntax** `maximum(expression[,group_by][,filter])`
>
> [ ] marks optional components
>
> **Arguments**
>
> *expression* sub expression of field to aggregate
>
> *group_by* optional expression to use to group aggregate calculations
>
> *filter* optional expression to use to filter features used to calculate aggregate
>
> Example: `maximum("population",group_by:="state")` → maximum population
>   value, grouped by state field

Comment: I don't know why, but this expression doesn't works. It says 'invalid expression.

Comment: I updated my answer. The issue was that I used `$z`, which calculates the z coordinate value of a 3D point. I missed the fact that your z values are stored as attributes, so I should have used `"z"`.

Comment: Now is selecting all the points.. LOL. Don't know what I'm doing wrong

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong, I'm just not on top of my game today. Updated again. Now it should select the point with the highest Z in each group.

Comment: That worked hahah Thanks! It was so simple. I need to study more about the sintax. :)

Answer (score 3):

SQL is the answer !

You can achieve this using the DB Manager of QGIS.

You choose **Database / Database Manager / Database Manager** then **Virtual Layers / Qgis Layers** you can then try queries like the following :

```
SELECT max(Z), pt_x, pt_y FROM my_table group by ID
```

You can then load the result in the layer manager.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This expression worked here. But I need a way to automatize this.  Is ti possible to create a plugin with DB  Manager and use it on Graphical modeler? This process is just a small part of my project that needs to be repeated a bunch of times, so doing this manually all the time is impossible.

Comment: You should edit your question then and give all the elements u need right from the start ...

Comment: sorry, I edited my question . Thanks for the help

Comment: what do u call your 'process' ? U don't give any information + there's nothing 'manual' in the 2 solutions that have been given to u ...

Comment: It is a lot of steps conected on graphical modeler. My question here is just one of these steps. So, all the steps togethers are my process that will be repeated hundreds of times