# Find Largest Building in each Parcel (largest feature in each groupby set)

Tags: postgis, attribute-table, grouping

I have a question similar to [this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/319044/171056), but the proposed approach doesn't seem to work.
For context, I am new to qgis.

Given a set of parcels, each with 0 or more buildings, I want to select only the largest building in each parcel.

There are about 200k parcels and 320k thousand buildings.

#### Example

```
Building A:
 parcel_APN: 1 (ParcelNumber)
 SHAPE_Area: 100 

Building B:
 parcel_APN: 1
 SHAPE_Area: 500

Building C:
 parcel_APN: 2
 SHAPE_Area: 50

>>> LargestBuildings: [B, C]
```

I tried two approaches:

#### SQL Query DB Manager

Seems like this should work, but I let it run for 2 hours and it did not finish.
Dataset is big, but seems to be shouldn't take that long for a SQL join.
A simpler SELECT with MAX area and groupby but without the join take less than  5 seconds.

The approach is to first group by APN to find the largest shape area, then do inner join using id and max area , with the same table, to retrieve the largest buildings.

```sql
SELECT * FROM
 ( 
   SELECT 
     parcel_APN,
     MAX(SHAPE_Area) as max_shape
   FROM buildings as t0
   GROUP BY parcel_APN
 ) as t1
JOIN buildings as t2
ON t1.parcel_APN = t2.parcel_APN and max_shape = t2.SHAPE_area
```

#### Using Attribute Expression

This is the approach suggested in the SO mentioned above:

```sql
maximum("SHAPE_Area", group_by:="parcel_APN")
```

I let this run last night, this morning was still running and eventually QGIS crashed.

#### Questions

Do these approach seem correct? Is there an easier way to go about this?
Are the file sizes too big for something like this in QGIS? And maybe I need to work in subsets or work with the data outside?

---

### Update

I created a small subset to test, and the **attribute expression** method does not seem to work - selects all buildings:

[image: screenshot attribute table not working]

### Update 2

DB Manager Query seems to work! I guess now I just need to find a way to run it without crashing QGIS, or load it into PostGIS to run it.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

While a SQL approach with DB Manager and Virtual layers inside QGIS worked with small samples, it would run for hours or crash agains the entire datates.

As suggested by @DSSPatial, I loaded the data into PostGIS and it worked really well, and fast. Here is the final query:

```sql
INSERT INTO main_buildings
SELECT 
    t2.*
FROM
 ( 
   SELECT 
     t0."parcel_APN",
     MAX(t0."SHAPE_Area") as max_shape
   FROM main_buildings as t0
   GROUP BY t0."parcel_APN"
 ) as t1
INNER JOIN main_buildings as t2
ON t1."parcel_APN" = t2."parcel_APN" and max_shape = t2."SHAPE_Area";
```

Not perfect but this is what I was looking for.

[image]

Comment: Try using the ST_Area() of the GEOM instead of SHAPE_AREA... glad you got it going in postgis!!!